# Android WebView width not corresponds to its html content

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to display an image using img html tag in a WebView. Image size is 120x90px and I tried to set the webview size to that size, even converting px to dp, but the webview always shows a white frame around the image and it has horizontal and vertical scroll.
This is my last attempt, image and webview sizes seem to be the same, but the white frame makes the webview scrolling.

```
WebView thumb = new WebView(this);
        thumb.setPadding(0, 0, 0,0);


        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float logicalDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
        double dp = (int) 120/(logicalDensity/160);


        String summary = "<html><body><img src='"+video_thumb+"' width="+dp+" style='margin:0;padding:0'/></body></html>";
        thumb.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);


        //thumb.loadUrl(video_thumb);
        main.addView(thumb,120,90);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting padding and margin to 0px in css?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using a WebView to display an image?

Comment: @CaseyB: I put them in the image tag as you can see. Do you mean maybe putting it for html and body tags? I use a webview as the image is on the web and I prefer not to download it.

Comment: @Tim: the image is on the web, I know that I should download it to use an imageview..or not?

Comment: @CaseyB: I tried putting padding and margin on body tag...it works...what a noob I am. Thank you